# how can i open big size html file?

Tags: html, browser

I am using python script for comparing the data and output of differences is saved into html file, but due to huge difference the result file turns into 158 MB size which I am unable open in any browser

How to open it or should I convert it into pdf or some other format on which I can open it?

Comment: Hi there, could you include a sample of your data, and post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is for rendering content for consumption. A 158MB web page is to large, a human can not be expected to process this amount of information in a single viewing.

Alter your script to restrict the number of displayed differences between files to more manageable amount and include the total number of additional differences a count.

eg:

```
<p>[X] differences identified between [file1] and [file2], the first 5 difference are listed below:</p>
<ul>
    <li>[line]:[difference]</li>
    <li>[line]:[difference]</li>
    <li>[line]:[difference]</li>
    <li>[line]:[difference]</li> 
    <li>[line]:[difference]</li>
</ul>
```

If you need to have all the differences available, consider a different file format. A plain text file will allow you to use the various large file viewing applications (top, more etc) available.